# trying to open a file located in D drive on command prompt using perl

Tags: perl, perl-io

I am trying to learn file handling in Perl, I want to open a .txt file located in D: drive on the terminal on Windows in read mode, so the code I am using is as:

```
open(DATA, "<D:/pay_info.txt") or die "Couldn't open file pay_info.txt, $!";
while(<DATA>) 
{ print "$_";}
```

it always shows

> Couldn't open file pay_info.txt, No such file or directory at
>   C:\perl\perl2.pl line 1.

what does it mean?

Comment: It means what it says. That file doesn't exist.

Comment: If you are just learning, you might want to read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html. The style you used is very much outdated. If you are using a book or a tutorial, it is badly out of date. I suggest you take a look at [the Perl tag wiki here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info), as it lists a lot of free high-quality up to date resources.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you say:

> I had to run with a space between < and D:/

Using the three-argument version of `open` would have avoided this issue. This has been the approach recommended in the Perl documentation for many years now.

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'D:/pay_info.txt')
  or die "Couldn't open file pay_info.txt, $!";

while (<$fh>) {
  print $_;
}
```

I've changed a few other things:

- Used a lexical filehandle (`$fh`) instead of a global one (`DATA`). Actually, `DATA` is a special filehandle in Perl so it shouldn't be used for in most code.
- Switched to using single quotes whenever possible (single-quoted strings recognise fewer special characters so it's a good idea to use them whenever possible).
- Removed unnecessary quotes in your `print` line (actually, the `$_` is optional there as well).
- Light reformatting to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the file `D:/pay_info.txt` exists? Perl is unable to locate that file on the base folder of drive `D:` (that is the meaning of the error message printed by your `die` statement).

Comment: it worked, just I had to run with a space between < and D:/

Comment: Good to here, nevertheless you should read at least the perldoc document above mentioned by @simbebque. Usage of the suggested three parameter form would have avoided the error, is safer, and the state of the art way to open a file in perl. Do not forget to specify the encoding.